# Why doesn't Visual Studio Code display that it is running on Ubuntu 21.04 taskbar?

Tags: gnome, 21.04, visual-studio-code

When I start Visual Studio Code in Ubuntu 21.04 I do not see the indicator on the task bar that it is actually running.  Notice that you can see that Thunderbird, FireFox & terminal have open windows in the following image:

[image: Ubuntu 21.04 taskbar]

OpenOffice is not running (so it doesn't show the red dot) but Visual Studio Code (v 1.61.2 x64) **is** running but still doesn't show the red dot on the task bar.

Do you know why this might be?

Also, running Gnome version 3.38.5

**Extra**

I also noticed that clicking the icon on the taskbar starts a new instance of Visual Studio Code every time (instead of switching to the running copy).
That's really annoying.  Must be a setting I've changed somewhere or something.  Not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this was odd. Further down my taskbar I found another VSC (Visual Studio Code) icon and it showed the windows (and red dot).
I moved it up to the favorites area and deleted the other icon from favorites and all is right now.